# How to set background image in navbar

Tags: rubymotion

I am using latest version of RubyMotion.

I am trying to set a custom background image on the navbar in RubyMotion. But I keep getting errors.

**This is my code in AppDelegate:**

```
dashboardController = DashboardController.alloc.initWithNibName(nil, bundle: nil)
nav_controller = UINavigationController.alloc.initWithRootViewController(dashboardController)

image = UIImage.imageNamed('navbar/background_navbar.png') 
nav_controller.appearance.setBackgroundImage(image, forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault)
```

**This is the error:**

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NoMethodError', reason: 'app_delegate.rb:10:in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:': undefined method `appearance' for #<DashboardController:0x6c4a9a0> (NoMethodError)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exception is telling you that `UINavigationController` doesn't have an `appearance` method.

If you want to change the appearance of all navigation bars in your app, you can call the `UINavigationBar` proxy with `UINavigationBar.appearance.setBackgroundImage(...`.

If you want to change just the `navigationBar` of the current `UINavigationController` then call `nav_controller.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(...`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good example: https://github.com/IconoclastLabs/rubymotion_cookbook/tree/master/ch_2/10_imagenavbar

Code for doing exactly what you want.

Comment: No, unfortunately not. I just adds an image to the navbar not set the navbar background image. Below answer solved it though :)